# Add class to li tag on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I add a class to an `<li>` element when it is clicked?

I have the following code:

```
<ul id="moodtabs" class="side bar tabs">
    <li id="tabs1" onclick="showStuff(this)" class="mbutton">Cheerful</li>
    <li id="tabs2" onclick="showStuff(this)" class="mbutton">Romantic</li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1" class="tabContent" style="display: block;">
    <h4>Content 1</h4>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2" class="tabContent" style="display: block;">
    <h4>Content 2</h4>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on the first `<li>` then content 1 is shown and the same will happen for the 2nd `<li>` with the 2nd content.

Here is my JS:

```
function showStuff(element)  {
    var tabContents = document.getElementsByClassName('tabContent');
    for (var i = 0; i < tabContents.length; i++) { 
        tabContents[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    var tabContentIdToShow = element.id.replace(/(\d)/g, '-$1');
    document.getElementById(tabContentIdToShow).style.display = 'block';
}

$('ul#moodtabs li').click(function() {
    $('ul li.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');
});
```

I'm trying to add a class `active` to the `<li>` tags so I can style them when they are active.

Comment: You should use e.g `data-id` to target specific element on click or use `index()`. You are quite overcomplicating it imho. And mixing obstrusive js and plain js method and jQuery isn't that great

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery in `showStuff()`? `$(".tabContent").hide()` instead of that loop.

Comment: It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/snyza6oy/4/ Are you executing the click binding after the `<li>` elements are loaded? Try putting the code in the `$(document).ready()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code already works (could be though better written)
But most probably you're missign to wrap your jQuery code in DOM ready:

```js
jQuery(function( $ ){ // DOM ready

  $('.tabs').each(function() { 
  
    var $tab = $(this).find(".tab");
    
    $tab.on("click", function() {
    
      var tabId = this.id.replace(/\D/g,'');

      $tab.not(this).removeClass('current');
      $(this).addClass('current');
      
      $(".tabContent").removeClass("current");
      $("#tabs-"+tabId).addClass("current");
      
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
.mbutton        {background:none;}
.mbutton.current{background:red;}

.tabContent        {display:none;}
.tabContent.current{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<ul id="moodtabs" class="side bar tabs">
  <li id="tabs1" class="tab mbutton">Cheerful</li>
  <li id="tabs2" class="tab mbutton">Romantic</li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1" class="tabContent">
  <h4>Content 1</h4>
</div>

<div id="tabs-2" class="tabContent">
  <h4>Content 222222</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: But this target same element `li` than `$(this).closest('li').addClass('current');`. I mean `$(this).addClass('current');` as same effect than `$(this).closest('li').addClass('current');` because `this` is the `li` and `closest()` includes element itself

Comment: Thanks for you help, I tried the above and it didn't seem to make any difference

Comment: His code already works as written, see my jsfiddle. He probably just forgot to put it in the document.ready.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I have noticed that, I started with the false presumption that  OP's code is actually wrong-*ish* :) edited to reflect the findings. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest binding would be

```
$('ul#moodtabs li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('current').siblings('li').removeClass('current');
});
```

You can also drop your javascript function entirely and have this be your full function

```
$('ul#moodtabs li').click(function() {
    var myTab = $(this).index();
    $(this).addClass('current').siblings('li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tabContent').eq(myTab).css('display','block').siblings('.tabContent').css('display','none');
});
```